# I want count uniques along with value in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 6 numbers in array .

```
string[] list = { "1", "1", "2","2","1","3" };
```

I want result like this. please help.

> "1" = 3
>      "2" = 2
>      "3" = 1

Comment: Make a loop through the list and count letters you want. It's the simplest and the most natural way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var itemCounts = list.GroupBy(l => l)
                     .Select(g => new { key = g.Key, count = g.Count()});
```

Comment: Nice, I had the same solution but you were faster :)

Comment: thanks sir , please one huge help for me now , if  i want get first 1 Max(count) from itemCounts along with key how to get please .

Comment: `var topItem = itemCounts.OrderByDescending(m => m.count).Take(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers in SearchArray >0. Here is an alternative approach

You can also write a function 
1) find Max  - One Loop

```
  for( int i=0;i<searchArray.length;i++){
    if (searchArray[i]>max) max=searchArray[i];
  }
```

2) Initialize an `Array[Max+1]= 0`

3) Loop thru each item and increment the size in Array

```
 for( int i=0;i<searchArray.length;i++){

     Array[searchArray[i]]++;
  }
```

Comment: Why would one use this `O(n*n)` algorithm while Linq is shorter and **faster**

Comment: I4V, do you really understand how Linq work? I don't think using loop is slower. Loop is always the basic of everything related to processing list and IEnumerable stuff.

Comment: @I4V i think this is not N^2 this is N+N  right 2N so in Big O notation this N order right ?

Comment: @KingKing, I guess *you* don't understand it. `GroupBy` uses HashSet internally which has `O(1)` complexity. @simplecoder, I though you used two nested loops, so forget my comment.

Comment: @I4V OK, if so, we can use HashSet for our collection and use loop outside without linq, however that's just an idea, I still love LINQ so much, but I also love the so-called loop in programming. :)

Comment: @KingKing of course,..